# How to create SHARED DRAWING TOOL using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have been install node.js v0.8.2. i want to make real time drawing using this i have also search about it that with socket.io we can do it but i am confused how to use it i have three files html and two javascript files

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Shared Drawing</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="drawing" width="1500" height="1200">
</body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
$(function(){

    // This demo depends on the canvas element
    if(!('getContext' in document.createElement('canvas'))){
        alert('Sorry, it looks like your browser does not support canvas!');
        return false;
    }

    // The URL of your web server (the port is set in app.js)
    var url = 'http://localhost:7680';

    var doc = $(document),
        win = $(window),
        canvas = $('#paper'),
        ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d'),
        instructions = $('#instructions');

    // Generate an unique ID
    var id = Math.round($.now()*Math.random());

    // A flag for drawing activity
    var drawing = false;

    var clients = {};
    var cursors = {};

    var socket = io.connect(url);

    socket.on('moving', function (data) {

        if(! (data.id in clients)){
            // a new user has come online. create a cursor for them
            cursors[data.id] = $('<div class="cursor">').appendTo('#cursors');
        }

        // Move the mouse pointer
        cursors[data.id].css({
            'left' : data.x,
            'top' : data.y
        });

        // Is the user drawing?
        if(data.drawing && clients[data.id]){

            // Draw a line on the canvas. clients[data.id] holds
            // the previous position of this user's mouse pointer

            drawLine(clients[data.id].x, clients[data.id].y, data.x, data.y);
        }

        // Saving the current client state
        clients[data.id] = data;
        clients[data.id].updated = $.now();
    });

    var prev = {};

    canvas.on('mousedown',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        drawing = true;
        prev.x = e.pageX;
        prev.y = e.pageY;

        // Hide the instructions
        instructions.fadeOut();
    });

    doc.bind('mouseup mouseleave',function(){
        drawing = false;
    });

    var lastEmit = $.now();

    doc.on('mousemove',function(e){
        if($.now() - lastEmit > 30){
            socket.emit('mousemove',{
                'x': e.pageX,
                'y': e.pageY,
                'drawing': drawing,
                'id': id
            });
            lastEmit = $.now();
        }

        // Draw a line for the current user's movement, as it is
        // not received in the socket.on('moving') event above

        if(drawing){

            drawLine(prev.x, prev.y, e.pageX, e.pageY);

            prev.x = e.pageX;
            prev.y = e.pageY;
        }
    });

    // Remove inactive clients after 10 seconds of inactivity
    setInterval(function(){

        for(ident in clients){
            if($.now() - clients[ident].updated > 10000){

                // Last update was more than 10 seconds ago.
                // This user has probably closed the page

                cursors[ident].remove();
                delete clients[ident];
                delete cursors[ident];
            }
        }

    },10000);

    function drawLine(fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
        ctx.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
        ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

});"
```

server.js

```
// Including libraries

var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    static = require('node-static'); // for serving files

// This will make all the files in the current folder
// accessible from the web
var fileServer = new static.Server('./');

// This is the port for our web server.
// you will need to go to http://localhost:7680 to see it
app.listen(7680);

// If the URL of the socket server is opened in a browser
function handler (request, response) {

    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response); // this will return the correct file
    });
}

// Delete this row if you want to see debug messages
io.set('log level', 1);

// Listen for incoming connections from clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // Start listening for mouse move events
    socket.on('mousemove', function (data) {

        // This line sends the event (broadcasts it)
        // to everyone except the originating client.
        socket.broadcast.emit('moving', data);
    });
});
```

how to use these files please tell me step by step 
i shall very thank full to you

Comment: FWIW node v0.8 is *really* old, you should consider updating to the newest stable version such as node v0.12.x or io.js v3.x.x (as of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a proper project folder hierarchy.
Something basic like this would be good:

```
root
  |-----public
          |----css
          |----js
```

Put your html files in the public folder.
The client.js file into public/js and the server.js file into root the folder

You will need to modify your server.js file to use the public folder as root by changing this:

```
var fileServer = new static.Server('./');
```

to

```
var fileServer = new static.Server('./public');
```

I assume you downloaded node.js and installed it. If you havent , got to https://nodejs.org/ and download it.
Now open a command-line tool and navigate to your project root folder.
Its a good practice to maintain a package.json file that will store information about your project and your dependencies. To create a new package.json file run this command:

```
npm init
```

You need to install your dependencies.To do so, run these commands and wait for it to install.

```
npm install --save node-static
npm install --save socket.io
```

Then run your server.

```
node server.js
```